# python plugin menu action in Composer menu

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, print-composer, qgis-2.12

I'm new developing plugins for QGIS and am working on a plugin to add some pictures on the Composer layout.

I think the appropriate place to have the plugin menu action is in the Composer menu where one can see what's going on, not the mainWindow where everything happens out of view.

There is little code around about plugins for the Composer.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a personnal menu to all composer windows :

```
for composerView in iface.activeComposers():
  windowComposer = composerView.composerWindow()
  menuBar = windowComposer.menuBar()
  menuBar.addMenu('&MyMenu')
```

Comment: @andy Don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers that help you.